# can we place a div inside an "a" tag according to the accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility

According to the HTML5 specification, we can place a div inside an `a` tag. Does accessibility recommend it as we can't place a block element inside an inline element?

I mean something like it:

```
<a href="#">
<div class="textpart">
  header                  
</div>               
</a>
```

Are there any accessibility problems with this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Try http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php

Comment: There is not any clear specification. So can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Please provide the source, because doing that  seems like something not to do, HTML5-wise. For accessibility, there shouldn't be any issues however if the `div` has more than a bit of text, it may be annoying to navigate

Comment: let's say there is a carousel in the banner section. I want to make the full carousel clickable. Then I have to put the whole banner section inside the "a" tag. But according to W3c we can't place a block element inside an inline element. So is it proper way of writing HTML code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can *not* make a block-level element a child of an inline-level element, validators will give you a high-five in the face with a chair.

You can however set an inline element inside of another inline element and then set it to `display: block;` and it will both validate and work...

```
<a>first line<span style="display: block;">second line</span>third line</a>
```